# Java Spring controler refuses all requests expect GET

Tags: java, angular, spring, cors

I am working on Java Spring application with frontend on Angular but I faced issue that I can't resolve without yours help. When I am making requests from Angular to Java only GET ones are passing but POST, DELETE and POST return following error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/patient' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Controler**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/patient")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
public class PatientController {

    private PatientService patientService;

    @Autowired
    public PatientController(PatientService patientService) {
        this.patientService = patientService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Patient>> getPatient() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(patientService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Patient>> postPatient() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(patientService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Patient>> putPatient() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(patientService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Patient>> deletePatient() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(patientService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Angular service**

```
  getPatients() {
    this.http.post(AppComponent.apiUrl + '/patient', this.httpOptions) 
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{ "/api*": {
    "target":"http://localhost:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug",
    "changeOrigin": true 
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does your `proxy.conf.json` includes `"changeOrigin": true` value?

Comment: Yes, I added this field and it didn't help. For now my proxy config looks like this:


`{
  "/api*": {
    "target":"http://localhost:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}`

Comment: does those end point react to a simple **curl** (or some other client like **postman**) requests from the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolved the issue.

I don't know why but CORS Fitler that is quite popular resolution for issues like that doesn't changed anything neiher the proxy config but adding CorsConfigurationSource bean and following lines to `configure` method resolved the problem.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Controlling access
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                ...
                .and()
                .cors()      
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Also the second one which was working for me was to add a following class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry
                    .addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowCredentials(false);
        }
}
```

But in this solution is also **essential** to add `.and().cors()` lines into security config.

Answer (score 0):

Not need to set `origins=*` in `@CrossOrigin` annotation, by default all origins are permited.

You tried to put the annotation at method level?

Comment: As you can see annotation is added at the class level as well with origins parameter. Yes, I also tried to set this on method level and it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

And make sure that your angular client sends his credentials:

```
httpOptions = {
  withCredentials: true,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Close, I found also a solution with this method but I also needed to add `allowedMethods("*")` and `allowedHeaders("*")`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying configuration of Angular. Just allowing cross origins wouldn't be enough. You also would need to allow methods and some headers. This configuration helped me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Value("${angular}")
  private String angularOrigin;

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(angularOrigin)
            .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin")
            .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin")
            .allowedMethods("PUT","GET","POST","DELETE","OPTIONS");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Also notice that there is an OPTION HTTP method that should be allowed.